# Inserting an image into a table cell google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to get an image inserted into a table cell inside a google document (not spreadsheet). I can get an image in to a paragraph but have not had luck with inserting right into a table or table cell.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you post code of inserting to paragraph?

Comment: Works for me using `Insert->Image...` and uploading or dragging and dropping. Are you trying to directly copy and paste an image?

Comment: @Conner I am talking about using google apps script to achieve this

Comment: code to post to paragraph is 
 doc.insertImage(1, resp.getBlob());

Comment: I can get the image in with the code I posted. That isn't a problem and it is well documented in the Google Script API - what I am trying to do is to get that image put into a specific table_cell in a google document table.

Comment: Found a way to achieve what I wanted:

Comment: Maybe you could post your solution code in an answer so that it can be useful to  someone else?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call TableCell's insertImage() method. From the sample code you posted it looks like you are calling that method on the Document, which will insert it into the root level of the doc instead.